# "Advantage of" vs "Advantage to"

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions

Take these sentences which make use of the noun *advantage*:

> 1. There are advantages and disadvantages to working in this industry.
> 2. The advantages and disadvantages of working from Home.

My question is: 
What is the difference between the use of prepositions 'to' and 'of' after advantage?

Also, sometimes people use phrases with 'to' like in the following:

> there are a couple elements to this process

Would it be correct to use 'of' (*a couple elements **of** this process*)?

Comment: It should be like, "...advantage of of a scheme to the socially insecure....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advantage to** is prefered using with very formal things. For example:

> The advantage to living in a big city is that one can have a higher chance securing a good job
>
> The advantages to having family and friends around in your life are ...

**Advantage in** is used in the opposite way, with small and particular things. For example:

> The advantages in brushing your teeth everyday are...
>
> The advantages in having a smartphone are...

**Advantage of** can be used in both situations (in academic writing I personally will use the two above for a good mark), and in any other situtations in the middle.

Comment: "Advantages in" is not a very common phrase, both of your examples work better with "of", and it doesn't related to the question.

Comment: I dont think this is it. What is formal about sentence number 2 that isn't formal in sentence 4? As far as I'm concerned, you can use "to" in either case.

Answer (score 0):

According to Longman’s Dictionary of Common Errors:

Use: 
There are (several/many etc) advantages to (doing/having) sth 
“to” is a preposition here and all prepositions are followed by Gerunds (doing/going/being etc)
For example: “There are advantages to working in a supermarket.”
“There are clear advantages to such an approach.”
“Are there any advantages in appointing coordinators?”

You may also use:
the advantages of (doing/having) sth:
For example: “He described the advantages of living in the countryside.” “The advantage of independence soon became clear.”

Comment: Are these direct quotes or paraphrases of the text?

Answer (score 0):

1. Advantage of + an object: *The advantages of the cellphone.* (The use of “to” here is not possible.)
2. Advantage to + somebody: *Having a lot of patrons has an advantage to him.* (The use of “of” is not possible here.)
3. Advantage of/to + ing : *The advantages of/to using the cellphone.*

Answer (score -5):

"Advantage of" is used to explain the benefits of something which is in support.
But "advantage to" is used to explain the benefits against something.

Comment: That doesn't sound right; both forms can be supportive, though *advantage to* can be followed by the beneficiary of the advantage (e.g. advantage to *you*). Please substantiate your assertion.